# Problem with quotes in rmarkdown to generate html with jinja

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, jinja2, quotes

I have a little problem trying to generate quotes in a html file throught a rmarkdown. Actually, I would like to generate some jinja inside my html and there come the problem.

If I do not escape the quote:

`{% extends "base.html" %}` in rmarkdown become

`{% extends “base.html” %}` in the html file which produce an error.

And if I do escape the quote:

`{% extends \"base.html\" %}` in rmarkdown become

`{% extends &quot;base.html&quot; %}` in the html file which produce an error too.

What is the solution ?
Thanks by advance !

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer after a discussion on another channel.

It is necessary to add a option in the yaml below the html_document:

`self_contained: false`

and use escape quotes `\"` to avoid smart transformations.